# .Net Maui Image with different format not working In IOS

Tags: .net-maui

.svg .xml Format Images not showing in ios devices

1. Added Images of different format in Resources/images (img1.svg, img2.xml)
2. Added image code in xaml : `<Image Source="img1.svg" />`

Comment: Does the image display properly on Android device? Have you set the `build action` of the image to `MauiImage` in the `Properties` window?

Comment: This could be a size issue. Not sure why, but a 45 by 45 at 408 bytes png image shows just fine in iOS. A jpg image like 460 by 460 at 40 kilobytes won't. How large is your image?

Comment: Try this library https://github.com/FreakyAli/MAUI.FreakyControls

Answer (score 1):

When you add an SVG image to MAUI it converts it to multiple PNG images at different resolutions. As per the (possibly new?) details on the [Image page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/images) you have to use .png as the extension for the image if you are requesting it as a file, or you can use the filename without any extension in XAML as that is a key for images found in resources.

Answer (score 0):

Image name should start and **end with character**
in lower case alpha numeric and under scroll allowed. in your case it is number